Show that any cubic polynomial in $x$ can be written as a cubic polynomial in $(x-1)$.

Show that any cubic polynomial in $x$ can be written as a cubic polynomial in $(x-1)$.

Not sure where to go with this but my approach has been as follows:
Assume:
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=e(x-1)^3+f(x-1)^2+g(x-1)+h$$
giving
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=ex^3-(3e-f)x^2+(3e-2f+g)x-(e+g-f-h)$$
equating coefficients gives:
$$a=e, b=f-3e, c=3e-2f+g, d=f+h-e-g$$
Not sure if this is sufficient as I'm not sure if equating coefficients is the way to go or how to show the given equating holds and is true.
Apologies if this question is unclear but I'm just a little stumped that's all.
Many thanks in advance.

your equations are ok but they must be solved for e,f,g,h, giving each of these as a formula in a,b,c,d

Geometrically, you are wanting to show that for a cubic polynomial, there exists another cubic that when moved 1 unit right gives the same graph. Which, assuming a domain of R is clearly possible.

Substitute $x=t+1$ in your first equation to get $a(t+1)^3+b(t+1)^2+c(t+1)x+d=et^3+ft^2+gt+h$. Now equating coefficients is much easier, and directly gives a solution for the new coefficients. Essentially you are working out $f(t+1)$, and showing that this is a cubic in $t$. You can then substitute $t=x-1$ (equivalent to $x=t+1$ we used before) to turn it back into $f(x)$ written as a cubic in $x-1$.

The argument you propose is correct, but require some calculations (namely you have to show that the system of equation s you wrote always admits a solution). Another way to see it is using the fundamental theorem of algebra. You have that any cubic polynomial can be written as
$$
f(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)(x-\lambda_3)
$$
For some complex valued $\lambda_i$. So
$$
f(x)=((x-1)-(\lambda_1-1))((x-1)-(\lambda_2-1))((x-1)-(\lambda_3-1))=g(x-1)$$
